# Why __proto__ is not own property on function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why Foo does not have own property called '**proto**'. Without Foo having its own '**proto**' property, how does the toString() method on the prototype chain get resolved?

```
function Foo() {
    
}
Foo.toString()                  // 'function Foo() {\n    \n}'
Object.hasOwn(Foo, 'toString')  // false (which means, toString() is on prototype chain)
Object.hasOwn(Foo.__proto__, 'toString') // true
Object.hasOwn(Foo, '__proto__') // false (why?)
```

The MDN reference for [**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) does not seems to indicate reason for above.

Comment: You realize that `__proto__` is deprecated and no longer useful, right?

Comment: The `__proto__` property is a getter which essentially returns `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` (that way, putting it on `Object.prototype` allows all objects that "inherit" from it to have the `__proto__` property)

Comment: @Pointy Yes, I do.

Comment: MDN does write "*The `__proto__` property is a simple accessor property on `Object.prototype` consisting of a getter and setter function.*", does this not explain the `hasOwn` results?

Comment: "*how does the `toString()` method on the prototype chain get resolved?*" - it resolves using the internal *[[prototype]]* chain. The `__proto__` property is an inherited getter for that internal field, not the data property where the chain link is stored itself.

Comment: Going by the diagram at [Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes), it made me assume that __proto__ property is on the object, although there is documentation specifies it as an accessor property.

Comment: From [Object Prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) *When you try to access a property of an object: if the property can't be found in the object itself, the prototype is searched for the property.* In this case, the property is *__proto__*,  which I thought was making *searching on prototype* possible. Also, at the same time *__proto__* is itself on `Object.prototype`, which makes me wonder how are we able to get to *Object.prototype.__proto__* from Foo. There's certainly a gap in my mental model.